# Terminate javascript execution

Tags: javascript

I can find a way to terminate my javascript execution from inside my first fetch:

```
document.querySelector('#elsubmit').onclick = (event) => {

      fetch('/', {

        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          nombrelink: nombrelink
        }),
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
          "X-CSRFToken": getCookie('csrftoken'),
          "Accept": "application/json"
        }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {
          

        if (result['nadie']) {
  

        }
        else {
          document.getElementById('spanthelinkbox').style.borderColor = 'red';
          document.getElementById('spanthelink').style.display = 'block';
          document.getElementById('spanthelink').innerHTML = 'Link ya tomado';
          event.preventDefault();
          return;
          return;
          return false
          return false
          return false

        }

    });

  
  fetch(`https://www.url.com/${urlname}`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
  
    headers: {
      "X-CSRFToken": getCookie('csrftoken')
    }
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => {
      window.location = "https://www.url.com/" + result['urlname'].toLowerCase() 
  })
  
  }
```

The code gets to the place where all of the `return false` are written but it fails to stop the next fetch from being run. I want to stop the last fetch from being executed but using  `return false`, `event.preventDefault();` , and `return;` doesnt seem to be working. It's like the parent event can't be stopped.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you throw an Error?

Comment: @Andrew I tried and doesn't work. The code always gets to the 2nd fetch somehow

Comment: fetch is asynchronous, so they are both running at the same time.... If you want to wait you need to use async and await.

Comment: preventDefault is not going to do anything, return is not going to exit, because it is asynchronous

Comment: @epascarello Could you help me out on implementing async await on those fetchs? I will accept your answer

Comment: `.onclick = async (event) => { const good = await fetch().then(()=> return true; }); if (good) await fetch(); }` return false if you do not want second one to run

Answer (score 0):

Fetch returns a promise, and you can chain multiple promises, and use the result of the 1st request in the 2nd request, and so on.

```
    var result =('/', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      nombrelink: nombrelink
    }),
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      "X-CSRFToken": getCookie('csrftoken'),
      "Accept": "application/json"
    }
    }).then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
    if (result['nadie']) {
   return (`https://www.url.com/${urlname}`, {
   method: 'POST',
   body: formData,
   headers: {"X-CSRFToken": getCookie('csrftoken')}
    })}
    else {
      document.getElementById('spanthelinkbox').style.borderColor = 'red';
      document.getElementById('spanthelink').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('spanthelink').innerHTML = 'Link ya tomado';
      event.preventDefault(); 
     return false;
    }

});

// I'm using the result variable to show that you can continue to extend the chain from the returned promise
result.then(function(r) {
  console.log(r); // 2nd request result
});
```